# UITableView indexPath of last row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to make the last row in a `UITableView` visible, after it has been added.  Right now, when I add a row and call reloadData, the table goes to the top.

I figure if I get the `indexPath` for the last row, that I can select that row and it should appear in the list.  I am unsure of how to get that value, or even if I am approaching this correctly.

How do I get an `indexPath` for a specific row?

Comment: after reload use **- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

Comment: **NSIndexPath** is a combination of sectionIndex and rowIndex you can make **NSIndexPath** by passing these two values. Here is example: **[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex  inSection:sectionIndex];**. In your case rowIndex is *arrayCount-1*.

Comment: Also for last row visibility you can set **tableView offset y co-ordinate**. Just set it **(contentSizeHeight-tableHeight)** it will show you up to last row. Example: **[tblView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, tblView.contentSize.height - CGRectGetHeight(tblView.frame)) animated:YES];** .... I'm answering in comment because I do not want to give a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please note that, you don't need to call the `reloadData` to make the last row visible. You can make use of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method.

You can use the below code to achieve your goal.

```
// First figure out how many sections there are
let lastSectionIndex = self.tblTableView!.numberOfSections() - 1

// Then grab the number of rows in the last section
let lastRowIndex = self.tblTableView!.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSectionIndex) - 1

// Now just construct the index path
let pathToLastRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: lastRowIndex, inSection: lastSectionIndex)

// Make the last row visible
self.tblTableView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(pathToLastRow, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: true)
```

Swift 4.0:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.none, animated: true)
```

Comment: What if last section is empty?

Answer (score 4):

You can use scrollToRowAtIndexPath with extension:

In Swift 3:

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToLastCell(animated : Bool) {
        let lastSectionIndex = self.numberOfSections - 1 // last section
        let lastRowIndex = self.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1 // last row
        self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: lastSectionIndex), at: .Bottom, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Shamsudheen TK's answer will **crash**

> **if there is no rows/sections in tableview.**

The following solution to avoid crash at run time

```
extension UITableView {
  func scrollToBottom() {

    let lastSectionIndex = self.numberOfSections - 1
    if lastSectionIndex < 0 { //if invalid section
        return
    }

    let lastRowIndex = self.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
    if lastRowIndex < 0 { //if invalid row
        return
    }

    let pathToLastRow = IndexPath(row: lastRowIndex, section: lastSectionIndex)
    self.scrollToRow(at: pathToLastRow, at: .bottom, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Note: If you are trying to scroll to bottom in block/clousure then you need to call this on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
}
```

Hope this will helps other

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others get indexPath for perticular sections like section 0.

After that call...add this methos in `cellFOrROwAtIndex`

`[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];` ..to scroll to specific indexPath in TableView.

Note:-But it still need scrolling of tableview in Downward direction.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `-reloadData` for this use case. What you're looking for is `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Feel free to ask if you want some usage examples or a more detailed explanation as to why using `-reloadData` send you to the top of the `UITableView`.

Comment: I want to take an action on a newly inserted cell, How to ensure that the cell is made? Because fetching the cell at that indexPath is giving me `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Not mandatorily required to get the indexpath of last row.
You can set the CGPoint of UITableview to show a last row you added.
I always use this code in my chat application to show a last added message.

```
//Declaration
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

//Add this executable code after you add this message.
var tblframe: CGRect = tableview.frame
tblframe.size.height = self.view.frame.origin.y
tableview.frame = tblframe
var bottomoffset: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, tableview.contentSize.height - tableview.bounds.size.height)
if bottomoffset.y > 0 {
    tableview.contentOffset = bottomoffset;
}
```

I hope it will work for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 +

```
 extension UITableView {
    func isLastVisibleCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        guard let lastIndexPath = indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last else {
            return false
        }
        return lastIndexPath == indexPath
    }
}
```